# Invalid date format causing ModelState to be invalid in controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am getting an invalid ModelState when data is returned from a View using an ajax call but only for edits. I am passing a datetime value from a SQL record to the view. The date shows up just fine in a Kendo UI DateTime picker. If I make a new selection from the datetime picker, I don't get the exception, it's only if I don't make any changes do I get the invalid error. Here is what the MVC controller is showing:

```
The value '/Date(1387443600000)/' is not valid for RequiredByDate."
```

What am I missing here? First time I have ever had an issue with a datetime field like this.

**EDIT:** Found out the date was being formatted in the view once the controller passed it in. Here is what I had to do before using it on the page and eventually sending it back to the controller (code is verbose for debugging purposes):

```
var myModel = model;
var jsonDate = myModel.Header.RequiredByDate; //  "/Date(1387443600000)/"
var value = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
var ret = value.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + value.getDate() + "/" + value.getFullYear(); 
//ret is now in normal date format "12-13-2013"
```

Comment: Maybe the CultureInfo settings affecting it

Comment: @Has AlTaiar, It's English. I use a lot of other dates in my application but only this one is screwing up

Comment: What is actually submitted to your controller? can you see that in Fiddler?

Comment: @trailmax, this is what I see going back to the controller, it is also what is being sent from the contoller to the view. RequiredByDate: "/Date(1387443600000)/"

Comment: @trailmax, Found the issue with the assistance of Amit from Microsoft. Turns out the controller was passing the correctly formatted date but in the page I am using Kendo MVVM and the model was converting the date to the value I posted above. Ended up having to do a javascript conversion. I have edited my post to show the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting an edit above I found what I think is an even better solution to the problem. Here is a function that converts the string to an actual date object:

```
function dateFromStringWithTime(str) {
    var match;
    if (!(match = str.match(/\d+/))) {
        return false;
    }
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(match[0] - 0);
    return date;
}
```